# Getting JSON from Contentful into Mustache

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, contentful

I'm trying to get my entries from Contentful (JSON) and putting them into a Mustache template.

The following code works, but is not applied to a template:

```
client.getEntries()
.then((response) => {
    $('.result').html(response.items.map((item) => ' Items: ' + item.sys.id).join('\n'));

})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log('\x1b[31merror occured')
    console.log(error)
})
```

When I try the same procedure but putting it into a template it doesn't work:

```
client.getEntries()
  .then((response) => {

    var template = $('#myEntries').html();
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, response.data);
    $('.result').html(html);

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error occured')
    console.log(error)
  })
```

HTML

```
<script id="myEntries" type="text/template">
    {{#items}} {{fields.customerName}} {{/items}}
</script>

<div class="result"></div>
```

It seems the JSON string is not properly attached to the template?

The JSON file looks like this

```
  {
     "sys":{
        "type":"Array"
     },
     "total":3,
     "skip":0,
     "limit":100,
     "items":[
        {
           "sys":{
              "space":{
                 "sys":{
                    "type":"Link",
                    "linkType":"Space",
                    "id":"4eewqivb4aog"
                 }
              },
              "id":"4moramDebKGsUwI2a6YOSe",
              "type":"Entry",
              "createdAt":"2017-03-31T17:31:25.994Z",
              "updatedAt":"2017-03-31T17:31:25.994Z",
              "revision":1,
              "contentType":{
                 "sys":{
                    "type":"Link",
                    "linkType":"ContentType",
                    "id":"customer"
                 }
              },
              "locale":"sv-SE"
           },
           "fields":{
              "customerName":"3",
              "customerUrl":"3"
           }
        },
        {
           "sys":{
              "space":{
                 "sys":{
                    "type":"Link",
                    "linkType":"Space",
                    "id":"4eewqivb4aog"
                 }
              },
              "id":"5M6NPWMve0YgMcSUcoAusk",
              "type":"Entry",
              "createdAt":"2017-03-31T17:31:51.535Z",
              "updatedAt":"2017-03-31T17:31:51.535Z",
              "revision":1,
              "contentType":{
                 "sys":{
                    "type":"Link",
                    "linkType":"ContentType",
                    "id":"customer"
                 }
              },
              "locale":"sv-SE"
           },
           "fields":{
              "customerName":"4",
              "customerUrl":"4"
           }
        },
        {
           "sys":{
              "space":{
                 "sys":{
                    "type":"Link",
                    "linkType":"Space",
                    "id":"4eewqivb4aog"
                 }
              },
              "id":"2ClsG24K5S6qiAYGi8gEQI",
              "type":"Entry",
              "createdAt":"2017-03-31T17:22:16.490Z",
              "updatedAt":"2017-03-31T17:22:16.490Z",
              "revision":1,
              "contentType":{
                 "sys":{
                    "type":"Link",
                    "linkType":"ContentType",
                    "id":"customer"
                 }
              },
              "locale":"sv-SE"
           },
           "fields":{
              "customerName":"5",
              "customerUrl":"5"
           }
        }
     ]
  }
```

Would be awesome to get some help with this :)

/ Oskar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you showed, it looks like you are passing the wrong data to the template, the response object does not have any `data` property. and it is a good practice to call `.toPlainObject()` so all the appended helper methods will be removed and you will end up with just the raw data

Your code should be

```
client.getEntries()
  .then((response) => {

    var template = $('#myEntries').html();
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, response.toPlainObject());
    $('.result').html(html);

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error occured')
    console.log(error)
  })
```